# Weird problem when using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: java, android

I have an activity where I have elements like, ImageView, Switch, EditText, TextView, when changing screen orientation some elements returned me to their initial value, to solve it use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to store and retrieve the information when changing the orientation of screen. It seems to work fine except for one detail with a Toast.

I have a TextView called dateOfNotification that shows a date that the user has selected, it starts with `visibility = "gone"`, I also have a Switch with the following code:

```
switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(switch1.isChecked()){
                if(dateOfNotification.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                    hour.setText("08:00");
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(tareas.this, "First enter a date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    switch1.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The important thing to note here is that switch1 cannot be activated if dateOfNotification is gone.

Now for the change of screen orientation without losing data I have:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState( final Bundle outState ) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putInt("visDate", dateOfNotification.getVisibility());
    outState.putBoolean("statusSW1", switch1.isChecked());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    dateOfNotification.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("visDate"));
    switch1.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("statusSW1"));
}
```

The problem is:

When dateOfNotification is visible and switch1 is Checked and I change orientation, values remain dateOfNotification is visible and switch1 is Checked, but I don't know why the Toast "First enter a date" shows me, It is assumed that when dateOfNotification is visible, the Toast should not be shown, the rarer is that to show the Toast, the dateOfNotification is considered to be hidden, but then why doesn't the switch disable me?

```
else{
                Toast.makeText(tareas.this, "First enter a date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                switch1.setChecked(false);
            }
```

It does not seem logical to me that only the `Toast.makeText(tareas.this, "First enter a date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` is executed and that the `switch1.setChecked(false);` is not executed

**EDIT**

By testing I understood what is happening, the state of switch1 is always saved with or without onSaveInstanceState, then when rotating the screen dateOfNotification is Gone, but the state of switch1 is retrieved and activated, when setOnCheckedChangeListener sees that switch1 has been activated dateOfNotification is hidden then it shows the Toast and the switch1 is turned off, then with onRestoreInstanceState the visibility of the dateOfNotification and the state of switch1 are recovered, then now it is activated again.

So I would like to know if there is some way to make the state of switch1 not load automatically when rotating the screen, which can only be loaded with onRestoreInstanceState

Comment: Where are you calling `setOnCheckedChangeListener`?

Comment: It's inside `onCreate`, and it is called when executing `switch1.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("statusSW1"));`

Comment: Add some lines to the query, you can read them to see if you can help me